# После поворота во фрагменте не отображается список

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview, асинхронность

Я сделал программу, которая получает данные с одного сайта и выводит их в виде списка во фрагменте. Программа работает, но при повороте с экрана исчезает список. С чем это может быть связано и как это решить?

```
 MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


   private Elements content;

   private ArrayList<NewsElement> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ArrayList<NewsElement> savedNewsList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ArrayList<NewsElement> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();
   boolean sl=false;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_parser, container, false);

        if(newsList.isEmpty()) {
            NewThread newThread = new NewThread();//Запускает поток, который    получает данные и передаёт их в Newslist
            newThread.execute();
        }

        if(savedInstanceState==null) {

            if(!sl) {
                fullSourceList();
                sl=true;
            }

            RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(view.getContext(), newsList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else{
            RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(view.getContext(), newsList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что при пересоздании у вас будет savdInstance и вы делаете сразу     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); (в этот момент данных в массиве нет)

Однако одновременно с этим запускается тред, который читает данные. Скорее всего этот тред не делает notifyDataSetChanged (проверьте). Также скорее всего данные от fullSourceList тоже не сохранились после смены ориентации.